# Debian: Set persistent custom time

Tags: linux, debian, date-time, ntp

I try to set a custom time on my (fresh installed) Debian system. For example, I want to set my time to 2013-05-05. So I disabled NTP on my system with `timedatectl set-ntp false`, verify that synchronization is disabled and set the time with `date -s 2013-05-05 13:00`. To make sure the hwclock is also set to that date I set it with `hwclock -w`. Both timestamps are now correctly set to that date. But when I reboot the system both timestamps are back to the "now" timestamp. Where is Debian to take that time from? I even unplugged my network and tried this, but the system keeps setting the time to "now" after a reboot.
What I found is that on a reboot there is a line in my `dmesg` which says `rtc_cmos 00:01: setting system clock to *now*` but from where does this timestamp come?

Comment: Check your crontab.

Comment: crontab is empty and /etc/cron.* is also just the default cron tasks. I used a fresh installed Debian to test this